# How to run zf2 with wordpress..?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework2

I have install zf2 with wordpress. Now wordpress is working fine but when i try to access puclic/index.php it showing internal server error. Below is my .htaccess in public folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to install a ZF2 app and Wordpress in the same folder?  If you're looking to integrate ZF2 code into Wordpress (or vice versa) there are a number of solutions out there, including http://www.wordpresszendframework2.com/ (disclaimer: I've never used it myself)

Comment: actually am working on a maintenance project so i cant build it from scratch in any new framework or whatever it is.

Comment: If it's maintenance of exsting work, did it ever work?  I would trace back to a time when it did work and find out what changed.  Without seeing your code or knowing your rationale for trying to run Wordpress and a ZF2 app from the same folder I can't help you.

Comment: It was working but in a different way.. wordpress interface is working from different link and zf2 from other. But now in new requirements i have to merge both.

Comment: The only way to truly run them both side-by-side in the same directory without modification is to manually map each possible URL path to the right application entry point file using web server rewrites.  Alternatively you can make one of the applications in charge of routing and have it dispatch the applicable requests to the other, which is exactly what Wopzen2 (wordpresszendframework2.com) does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move all your wordpress files to a particular folder like I have done in my pages folder and update the ZF2 base htaccess as below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/pages [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```